# can anyone teach me how to install mysql connector in java....?

Tags: java

I am a beginner in Java and I want to connect to a mysql database in Java.  I have downloaded mysqlconnector.

I have extracted the files into tomcat lib paths but still I am unable to connect to database.

C:\tomcat\lib\mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin

I am using Eclipse and I have also installed wampserver.

Please help...

I want to connect to a database. How should I install my connector?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the mysqlconnector jar to your classpath, and use a simple JDBC java program to connect to the Database.

See http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/how-to-connect-to-mysql-with-jdbc-driver-java/

Answer (score 1):

Add the following to your Maven projects pom.xml file in the dependencies section:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.30</version>
</dependency>
```

You may need a different version if so, look [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java) for the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

Make lib folder in your project, copy jar in there, then right click on 
your_project and go to Properties->Java Build Path->Libraries and add your jar to project's class path